# How to check if the Powershell cmdlet Get-AzKeyVaultSecret supports -AsPlainText parameter?

Tags: azure, powershell, parameters, azure-keyvault, powershell-cmdlet

With the following command I am able to retrieve a list (or is it a dictionary? My Powershell knowledge is unfortunately very limited) of parameters supported by the `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $params = (Get-Command Get-AzKeyVaultSecret).ParameterSets | Select -ExpandProperty Parameters

PS C:\> $params | ForEach {$_.Name}
VaultName
Name
InRemovedState
DefaultProfile
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
...
```

How could I please check if the list contains the `AsPlainText` parameter, which was added in the newer versions of the cmdlet?

In my custom script I would like to check for that and then adapt the way I retrieve a secret value from a key vault:

```
if ($is_AsPlainText_Supported) # how to set this variable?
{
    $mySecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MySecret' -AsPlainText
} 
else
{
    $mySecret = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MySecret').SecretValueText
}
```

I would prefer not to use `try/catch`here (or check if retrieved secret value is `null`), because I have numerous `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` calls in my real script and such approaches would cost performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line before your if statement:

```
$is_AsPlainText_Supported = (Get-Command Get-AzKeyVaultSecret).ParameterSets.Parameters.Name -contains "AsPlainText"
```

The `-contains` operator will return a boolean based on if the list before the operator contains the item after it.